# Using MathJax without encapsulating strings? (e.g. a^2 instead of $ a^2 $)

Tags: javascript, latex, user-input, mathjax

I am working on adding LaTeX support to an app which will display user-generated input. However not all of my users are very technically savvy. I know that LaTeX isn't the easiest to use for complex equations, but to display simple exponents I think my users can handle it. Generally I want to make it as easy to use as possible which means removing any and all barriers to usage. One of them is the use of encapsulating strings, such as `$...$` or `\(...\)`.

Is there a way to get MathJax to parse an entire webpage or div, not simply the text within the encapsulating strings?

Comment: How do the users generate the input? Do they use forms?

Comment: Yeah, they type it into a field and the output is displayed with formatted math. I would prefer if the entirety of their input was formatted, not just the substrings between `$...$`

Comment: Check out [this sample](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html) which does what I think you are asking for.